# how to use RxJS do this job

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

everyone,
I'm learning Web App program use Angular 2, and I want implement a Service.

This service like this:

```
@Injectable
export class MyService {
  private _data: Any;
  private _dataReady: boolean = false;

  getData(): Observable<any> {

    if (this._dataReady)
      return Observable.of(this._data);
    else {

       http.get('url').subscribe(response=>{
          this._data = do_some_calc(response, this._data);

          if (need_more_data(this._data)) {
             Recursive http.get('url')....
          } else {
             this._dataReady = true;
             return Observable.of(this._data);
          }

       });
    }
  }

}
```

the difficult part for me is when data is not ready, need get some data from web, and depend the information from the new arrived data, may be need get another data from web again.

how implement this part and finally return client a Observalbe?

I know how to implement this use callback function , but I very interest how to use RxJS implement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd chain multiple `concatMap` operators if the request depend on each other:

```
http.get('url')
  .concatMap(response => {
    this._data = do_some_calc(response, this._data);

    if (need_more_data(this._data)) {
      return http.get('url')
        .concatMap(response => { ... })
        .concatMap(response => { ... });
    } else {
      this._dataReady = true;
      return Observable.of(this._data);
    }
  })
  .subscribe(response => { ... });
```

Or you can make a recursive function that returns an Observable and calls itself:

```
function recursiveGet(url): Observable {
  return http.get('url')
    .concatMap(response => {
      if (need_more_data(this._data)) {
        return recursiveGet(url);
      } else {
        this._dataReady = true;
        return Observable.of(this._data);
      }
    });
}
```